# API java for Web service monitoring

Tags: java, web, service, monitoring

I want to find an API  java  that enables the monitoring of the response time and the availability of a given Web service ?

Thanks.

Comment: set up a cron with curl usage..

Comment: Please, can you give more details. I'm beginner in the domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not hosting that web service so you can not monitor it that well. But you can be a regular client to that web service.

Use a [cron](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) (repeated process) and make it to call that web service everytime to see responseTime and if you get error 404(resource not found http error) then it's unavailable. [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) can be used to make web service calls or you can use [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) that is a tool for calling SOAP web services and it has a runner that can send multiple repeated requests.